# Objects return as Defaults when using Dapper with a Constructor with 1 Parameter

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, dapper

I am trying to call a constructor with 1 parameter. The Query without the contructor parameter returns the values as expected. However, if I want to call the class with the additional parameter, I get the result counts as expected, but the values are all set to defaults.

Employee.cs

```
        public Employee(AppSettings appSettings)
        {
            employeeRepo = new EmployeeRepo(appSettings);
        }

        public Employee()
        {

        }
```

Database Call in the Repository

```
using (SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                string sQuery = "select * from dbo.tblEmployees";;

                var result = dbConnection.Query<Employee>(sQuery).Select(row => new Employee(_appSettings));
                var result2 = dbConnection.Query<Employee>(sQuery);
            }
```

[var Result - With empty Constructor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrPPV.png) 
[var Result2 - Calling constructor with parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnX8o.png)

I've tried various implementations of the above. I was initially brought to the custom constructor call by this post: [Call custom constructor with Dapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8994933/14766428)

I also tried fully qualifying the select statement and that didn't seem to work either based on this post: [Dapper strongly typed Query returning default object values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41149588/dapper-strongly-typed-query-returning-default-object-values)

I've also tried:

```
var result3 = dbConnection.Query<dynamic>(sQuery).Select(row => new Employee(_appSettings));
```

But anytime I started to use the Constructor with the parameter, I get the default values for all my objects back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include property sets in `.Select` method. For exmaple:

```
  public class Employee
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public AppSettings Settings { get; set; }

    public Employee() { }
    public Employee(AppSettings appSettings) { Settings = appSettings; }

    ...
    
    var result = dbConnection.Query<Employee>(sQuery).Select(row => new Employee(settings) {Id = row.Id, Name = row.Name});
  }
```

Also you can use [AutoMapper](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html) for avoiding complex setter's calls:

```
      var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Employee, Employee>()
        .ForMember(x => x.Settings, opt => opt.Ignore()));

      var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

      var result = dbConnection.Query<Employee>(sQuery).Select(row =>
      {
        var obj = new Employee(settings);
        return mapper.Map(row, obj);
      });
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to implement AutoMapper to the effect I need it!